# typedef type mismatch passing it into a function

Tags: c++, typedef

I have a header that has

```
typedef double func(double)
```

and a function declaration in a header called

```
double function(func f);
```

This is defined to do something in a corresponding .C file. So, to access this I have a file main.C that contains

```
#include"necessaryheader.h"

double f(double x){
  return 1.0;
}

int main(){
  func f;
  double x = function(f);
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

But when I attempt to compile this it throws an error

```
undefined reference to `function(double (*)(double))'
```

Why is this, is that not exactly the type that 'function(func f)' takes as a parameter? 
A better question is how do I make the types match?

Comment: Your "function in a header" is only a declaration, not a definition.  The error is saying that you never defined `function`, so the linker doesn't know what to call.  It's not a type mismatch.

Comment: the function is appropriately defined in a corresponding .C file.

Comment: @Escap3faith but, are you actually compiling that file and linking the resulting obj file into the final executable? It sounds like you are not doing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef double func(double)
```

Should be

```
typedef double (*func)(double);
```

And make sure you are linking to a source file that contains the actual implementation of `function()`.

And you need to get rid of the `func f;` declaration in `main()`.